# use notepad++ to format data

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 1      -0.151714363660730E+03       0.681572558518519E+02
  -0.147787110884357E+03       0.702453634941157E+02
  -0.147765104000000E+03       0.702198060000000E+02
  -0.147681722000000E+03       0.701999540000000E+02
  -0.147648000000000E+03       0.702032990000000E+02
  -0.147585678000000E+03       0.702033980000000E+02
  -0.147505270000000E+03       0.702003840000000E+02
  -0.147431532000000E+03       0.701888260000000E+02
  -0.147402283000000E+03       0.701852730000000E+02
```

how can I use find and replace in notepad++ to put all the data on one line

Comment: Hard to say. Is it space or tab characters?

Comment: What's with that lone 1 there?

Comment: and the programming question?

Comment: @BoltClock: is that relevant for the answer?

Comment: Use VI. http://www.vim.org/download.php
ggVGJ

Comment: I don't care if the question is unclear or whatever, +1 to counter all the prejudice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press ctrl+h
2. Select 'extended'
3. Replace all `\r\n` with `` (CR+LF line endings)
4. Replace all `\n` with `` (LF line endings)

Answer (score 2):

The general algorithm:

1. Switch to advanced search mode
2. Replace all `\r\n` to space
3. Replace all `\n` to space
4. Switch to RegExp search mode
5. Replace `\s+` to space

*HINTS:

1. depending on encoding of the endline symbol point 2 or 3 can be excluded.
2. I don't have English version of notepad++, and my translation of search modes could be incorrect.

**Hey, and now where is the part about single space delimiter?**

If you do not need it, just remove steps 4-5.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be only a simple search and replace with this params:

from: "       "

to: " "

But it's trivial, and I assume it wouldn't work, just because you asked this question. I don't know anything about your files, but there is another way to complete tasks like this using Notepad++.
You can use "**Macros**" very simply. You have to click to the "**Recording Macros**" button (Macros menu), and show a repeatable solution only for 1 line. After that you can **stop the recording**, and **with Ctrl+Shift+P** you can repeat it very quickly. It's a very useful and general solution, since i've found it I use it all the time to solve this kind of problems.